# React App: Failed to Compile. Module parse failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[image]

Everytime I create React app and start the development server, I get this error. HELP!!!

Comment: can you clarify when exactly this error appears? is this occurring for old CRA that you are trying to run? Or does this occur with every new CRA that you create? When you run CRA, do you get any warnings or messages?

Comment: It always occur whenever I create new CRA

Comment: Can you confirm you are running `npx create-react-app [app name]` and not `npm`? Can you also run `npm --version` to see what version of node you are running?

Comment: Yes I am exactly running the app using npx create-react-app [app name] and the version for npm is 7.19.1

Comment: Hmm. Wanna run `npx create-react-app [app name]`, then run `rm -rf node_modules` inside the app directory, then re-install the dependencies using `npm install`? Try that and see if t he app runs. Not sure why CRA is downloading dependencies that don't work.

Comment: I also recommend reading this thread 

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try!

Comment: Its not helping. Any other way to fix this??

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518) issue, it may be a problem with the `react-scripts` part of your library. So either use a specific, older version of create react app by running :

```
npx create-react-app@4.0.1 my-app
```

Or by running CRA as is, then modifying your `package.json` folder so that the react script version is specified.

So after you run CRA, change your `package.json` file like so:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1"           // change this line to 4.0.1
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then make sure you `rm -rf node_modules` then run `npm install` to get a fresh install that removes whatever `react-scripts` came by default so that you use the specific 4.0.1 version.